# iOS: Sorting an array of UIButtons based on their position in relation to their siblings?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sorting, subview

I have a `NSMutableArray`, called `self.tappableButtons`, of `UIButtons` which all share the same parent view. At times they overlap, and I would love to sort my array based on their order in relation to each other (starting with the topmost button to the bottommost one in the hierarchy). What's the easiest way to achieve this?

I'm basically using fast enumeration to check if the current touch in my custom pan gesture recognizer falls within a button's bounds. The problem is that if two buttons overlap it returns the one that came first in my array when enumerating, rather than the topmost button within an overlap.

```
//Search through all our possible buttons
for (UIButton *button in self.tappableButtons) {
     //Check if our tap falls within a button's view
        if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.bounds, tapLocation)) {
            return button;
        }    
}
```

Comment: are you creating buttons programmaticaly ?

Comment: I'm using a storyboard to create them, but can access them using tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way (without knowing more of your code) is probably to use the `subviews` order to determine the topmost button on your touch.

```
UIView* buttonParentView = ....
NSEnumerator* topToBottom = [buttonParentView.subviews reverseObjectEnumerator];

for (id theView in topToBottom) {
     if (![self.tappableButtons containsObject: theView]) {
         continue;
     }

     UIButton* button = (UIButton*)theView;
     //Check if our tap falls within a button's view
     if (CGRectContainsPoint(button.bounds, tapLocation)) {
         return button;
     }    
}
```

If this function is executed a lot and your `self.tappableButtons` remains relatively stable, or your parentview has a -lot- of subviews that are not in `self.tappableButtons` it's probably better to simply use your function but sort the tappableButtons first based on where they appear in their parents subviews.

Comment: This looks promising thanks Pieter! Will try and report back. With that said, is there a method I can call using `topToBottom` to omit anything not in self.tappableButtons so that I can do something like `for (UIButton *button in topToBottom) {}`

Comment: You could use filteredArrayUsingPredicate if you wanted, I'm not convinced it would make the code clearer though

Comment: Thanks Pieter so it turns out they don't directly share the same parent view (more like great grandparent) however in the case that they do your code works great!